# How to convert an AJAX error code generated at runtime into a php variable for analysis

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using an ajax function in my code. If an error occurs a div shows the error number. I need this error value for a further database query on same page. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the value to the PHP file you're using to process those values.

To do this asynchronously, use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or one of it's simpler [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) siblings.

So, your workflow will be

1. Capture the error number in javascript variable.
2. Make an AJAX request, sending this variable in the `data`.
3. Process the request in your PHP file.